# Google+ API Pricing

Tags: google-plus

I notice that the Google Plus API has a courtesy limit of 10,000 requests per day. I can't seem to find any information on whether or not it is possible to raise this by paying.

Is this possible? Otherwise I can see no point in even considering integrating with Google+.

Comment: Does this help? https://developers.google.com/console/help/#billing

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It doesn't cost money to request quota for the Google+ API. You need to submit an application for more quota, and have it approved.

To increase your Google+ quota:

1. Visit the [Google APIs Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console). (Make sure you've enabled the Google+ API under **services**.)
2. Click "**Quotas**" on the menu.
3. Look for "**Google+ API**", and click "**Request more...**"